# Database design SQL user can have multiple educations

Tags: sql, database

I am a novice when it comes to database design.

Currently I have a user table with attributes like id, email, first/last name, password.

A user can have multiple educations.

So I was thinking a table with id(user id), program, school, date start, date end. But if doing so, the table won't have a primary key.

Should have make another id for education? What's a better design? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's perfectly acceptable to add an education id to the database. This will let you identify a particular education record.

Later, if your app grows, you'll be able to attach things to those education records. Eg, if you want to detail courses taken at different schools,  you would use education id on the courses table to tie it back.

Comment: I think your answer fits my project better. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can have multiple educations why not have a link table;

Educations

```
EducationID
EduationName
etc
```

And

UserEducations

```
UserID
EducationID
```

This would allow for multiple Educations to be assigned to the user